# Lambda function calling another lambda function in Excel?

Tags: excel-lambda

I am trying to create an Excel lambda function that calls another lambda function. But Excel returned `#VALUE!` when I ran it. Does Excel support this kind of operation?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just call the `mylambda1` function within the `let` function as follows:

```
mylambda1 = lambda(a, b, a+b)
mylambda2 = lambda(a, b, let(x, a, y, b, mylambda1(x,y)))
```

[image]

#### Output

[image]

#### Cheers!